# Geometrical interpretation of $\pi=\int_0^1\frac{4}{1+x^2}dx$.

Tags: integration, geometry, pi

How to show that
$$\pi=\int_0^1\frac{4}{1+x^2}dx?$$
I know how to do it symbolically by using that $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan x=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. But is there a **geometrical interpretation** of this result?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r1a6zvmt1d , try linear approximation to find it's area. Not the best figure for a curve I'd add tho. ^^

Comment: Or maybe Riemann sum, for a better approximation. This should show why area is $\pi$ specifically.

Comment: (possibly related) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612147/how-to-demonstrate-the-equality-of-these-integral-representations-of-pi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the unit semicircle in the upper half-plane and the line $y=1$.

[image]

With a little geometry, one can show that
$$\mathrm dl=\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}.$$
Therefore, integrating $\mathrm dx/(1+x^2)$ over $x\in[0,1]$ gives you the circumference of the $45^\circ$ arc bounded by $x=0$ and $x=y$.

(This is just the geometrical interpretation of the substitution $x=\tan\theta$.)

Answer (score 11):

The substitution

$$
x = \tan\left[\frac{ t\sqrt{1-t^2} + \arcsin t }{2}\right]
$$
turns the integral into
$$
\int_0^1 4\sqrt{1-t^2} dt.
$$
But this is exactly four times the area of a quarter unit circle, hence equals $\pi$.

Comment: That is awesome! How did you get it?

Comment: Just the same thing I pondered! ^^

Comment: @Jakubussimus: Look at the area of a sector of the unit circle with central angle $t$.

Comment: Well, substitutions are not really allowed... If it were, then, the substitution $x=\tan t$ turns the integral into $$\int_0^{\pi/4}4dt$$ which is $4$ times a rectangle of area $\pi/4$. This is not interesting. I want a geometrical interpretation of $\int_0^1\frac{4dx}{1+x^2}$ whit respect to $x$.

Comment: If you figure out where the substitution comes from, this *is* precisely working out the area of the unit circle. The question is: What is $x$?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cxe5q2vpyr , well seems like I found something new.

Comment: I invented the substitution by working backwards from the area of the unit circle. I agree with Ted Shifrin that an interpretation of $x$ is desired.

Comment: @user111187 If you could provide a geometrical interpretation of $x$, it would answer my question.