# Show by direct substitution that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx = \int_0^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$

Tags: integration, substitution

I have the following problem: Show by direct substitution ($t=x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$) that $\int_0^{\infty}1/(1+x^2)dx = \int_0^{1}1/\sqrt{1-t^2}dt$.

This is a dumb question but I have not done this in a while and it has take me quite some time to do it. I feel there is a clean way to do it but every approach I take just gets messy. I can rearrange the substitution to obtain $x^2=\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}$, and then $1+x^2=\frac{1}{1-t^2}$. But any attempt at substituting this in just gives me $1-t^2$ in the numerator. The limits I am able to get by just looking at $t=x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$ going to the limits. When calculating $dt = \frac{\frac{1-x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{1+x^2}$. But this just gets nasty.

Please enlighten me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Use arctan

Comment: I have to do it by substitution using t.

Comment: One of my first questions here :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612147/how-to-demonstrate-the-equality-of-these-integral-representations-of-pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but when calculating $\mathrm{d}t$ you made a mistake. Since
$$t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$
You have that
$$\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$
Since
$$x^2=\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}$$
$$\sqrt{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$
Finally
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

Comment: So just to confirm, in the last statement, you reason $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}dt =\int_0^{+\infty}\sqrt{1+x^2}dt =\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dt $

Comment: Yes, you are correct @DjuroPucar

Answer (score 2):

Use subtitution: $x=\tan\arcsin t$.

In addition, Just notice its indefinite integral, You can easily come to this subtitution.($\arctan x=\arcsin t$)

This answer is equivalent to other answers，because:

$$\tan x =\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}= \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt[]{1-\sin ^2 x} }\quad (0<x<\frac{\pi}{2} )$$

We have $\tan \arcsin t = \frac{t}{\sqrt[]{1-t^2} } $.

Comment: While this sounds crazy, just take into account that $x=\tan (\arcsin t)$ can be simplified to $x=t/\sqrt{1−t^2}$ which is equivalent to the proposed substitution of $t=x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$. So this is a valid approach.

Comment: The OP is not asking about an alternative sub, in this case it is not even necessary since the integral is simply $\pi/2$

Comment: @SineoftheTime OK I have edited it.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}},$$
than
$$\textrm{d}t = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}\;\textrm{d}x.$$
Thus, this gives:
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\;\textrm{d}t = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\cfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)^2}}\cdot \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}\;\textrm{d}x$$
Which finaly gives:
$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt{1+x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}\;\textrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}\;\textrm{d}x$$

Comment: I was considering multiplying in the square going from dx to dt, but then I thought about whether that is allowed. Sometimes when multiplying in the equation $\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}$ might go to zero in the denominator in an interval between [a,b]. Would that be problematic?

Comment: @DjuroPucar I'm not sure I understand your question. Generally, caution needs to be maintained near the roots of denominators. In this case however, in the range of the integrand, the denominator does not have any roots.

Comment: So the roots of denominators would be problematic if they are in the range of the integrand. That is what I was getting at. How does one avoid these cases? Does one just choose a better substitute? Does one pursue other integration techniques? Is the integral simply indefined?

Comment: @DjuroPucar If you have an integrand with vertical asymptotes within the bounds of the integration, range, or the bounds of the integrations are infinite, a common approach is to compute the limits of the integral towards these vertical asymptotes or infinite boundaries. However, often a simple substitution can make them magically disappear. You can often see if the asymptotes will give problems if you take the Taylor expansion of the integral around those points.

Comment: Thank you! Could you link any problems where vertical asymptotes are dealt with? I understand one can take limits with proper integrals, but I can not understand how vertical asymptotes can be dealt with. Would not the "area" beneath be infinite?

Comment: @DjuroPucar It is not because a function goes to infinit, either horizontally or vertically, that its integral has to be infinite. So if you have an assymptote at $x=c$, than you can just compute $$\int_a^b = \lim_{\epsilon->0} \int_a^{c-\epsilon} + \int__{c+\epsilon}^b$$